# Android - BottomSheet not closing properly

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

**Situation :** I have a `BottomSheet` that expands on a button click (fig. 1), on the upper right corner of the `BottomSheet` I put an `ImageView` that works as a closing button, in other words when the `ImageView` is clicked the `Bottomsheet` state will be changed to `HIDDEN`

**what I tried :**
I tried to assign the imageview an `onTouchListener` (check code take #1) but I got a `NullPointerException` mainly because the bottomsheet was hidden and the imageview is not visible to user so I tried adding an if to check if the bottomsheet state is expanded and if so do the closing stuff (check code take #2)

[image: fig 1]

**Code take #1**

```
//this is where I got the NullPointerException
CloseSheet.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

**Code take #2**

```
//this is where I dont get a response on click
if(bottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED ){
        CloseSheet.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why have set onTouchListener on the Sheet itself, instead get reference of the ImageView and set its onClickListener. Refer this : http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-material-design-bottom-sheets-tutorial/

Comment: @Harjot Singh Oberai If you are talking about that `CloseSheet` it's not the BottomSheet itself that's the ImageView (the small red X circle)

Comment: sorry, my bad. So is it working now after referring the link?

Comment: No, still nothing !